# Rename part of file

Tags: vbscript, rename, file-rename

I require a VBScript that finds the most recent file in a folder and renames it.  I have been able to write the script so that it finds the most recent file. However, I cannot figure out how to correctly have the file renamed once identified.  I have been able to rename the file with a basic name, confirming the script works.

The file name needs the letter "A" added in the middle.

The file will already be saved as `20160229_TITLES` and it needs to become `20160229A_TITLES`.

Below is a script I tried to just pull the year and add the "A".  I figured if I could get the year to add to the beginning, I could then add in the month and year.  The date will always be the current date.  This continues to cause an error message.

```
Option Explicit

Dim fso, folder, file, Date, recentFile
Dim folderName, searchFileName, renameFileTo

folderName   = "C:\Ticket\Test\"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(folderName)  
Set recentFile = Nothing

For Each file In folder.Files    
    If (recentFile is Nothing) Then 
        Set recentFile = file
    ElseIf FormatDateTime(file.DateLastModified) = Date Then 
        Set recentFile = file 
    End If
Next

recentFile.Name = Replace(recentFile.Name, "_", "A_")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer @Ansgar provided helped me correctly rename the file, however, I learned that the script only searched for any file that was newer than any other file and renamed it.  The following script correctly renames the file that was modified today.  Thank you for all your help @Ansgar.  :)

```
 Option Explicit

 Dim fso, folder, file, todaysDate, recentFile
 Dim folderName, searchFileName, renameFileTo

 folderName     = "C:\Ticket\Test\"
 todaysDate     = Date()

 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
 Set folder = fso.GetFolder(folderName)  
 set recentFile = Nothing

 For each file In folder.Files    
     If (recentFile is Nothing) Then 
          Set recentFile = file
     ElseIf DateValue (file.DateLastModified) = todaysDate then
          Set recentFile = file
          Exit For
     End IF
 Next
 recentFile.Name = Replace(recentFile.Name, "_", "A_")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the filename will always consist of a date followed by an underscore and some other text you could do several things:

- replace underscores with "A_" (if there is only one underscore in the name):

  ```
  file.Name = Replace(file.Name, "_", "A_")
  ```
- split the name at the first underscore, append "A" to the first fragment and join the fragments back together:

  ```
  arr = Split(file.Name, "_", 2)
  arr(0) = arr(0) & "A"
  file.Name = Join(arr, "_")
  ```
- do a regular expression replacement:

  ```
  Set re = New RegExp
  re.Pattern = "^(\d{8})_"
  file.Name = re.Replace(file.Name, "$1A_")
  ```

Comment: Thank you.  I used your first example and was able to rename a file within the folder, however, it is now changing the file name of the second oldest file in the folder and not the newest.

Would you happen to know why it's no longer renaming the most recent file?  

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Remove the `Exit For` from your loop. You *must* compare *every* file in the folder. As it is now the loop will exit after the first file that is newer than the first file in the folder. And rename that file.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Unfortunately, I still can't seem to get it work.  I removed the 'exit for' and now I am getting an error on the line where I rename the code.  

Error: Object required: "

The rename worked fine before I removed the "Exit for" (except it renamed the wrong file)

Maybe I'm going about this wrong.  The purpose of the script is to find the file that was saved today and rename it.  I do not need to go through all of the other files, I just need to find today's.  Would you able to offer assistance with that?  Thank you!

Comment: @jodies `recentFile.Name = Replace(recentFile.Name, "_", "A_")`

Comment: Thank you. The name change works perfectly now. I have made changes to the script so that once it locates the file that was modified today, that it will rename it.  However, the script renames the oldest file in the folder, not the newest.  What am I missing so that it finds the one file that was modified today? I'm very grateful!  I'm new and learning and appreciate your time.